# How can I fix the DatePicker Invalid prop value of type string error in my React with Redux and KendoUI Web Application?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, redux, kendo-ui

I'm currently working on my React with REdux application for ASP.NET Core using the Kendo React UI from Telerik.  I'm using their grid widget, which, seems to be working ok until you try to edit one of the rows.  When you try to edit a row you get the following error:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `String`
>   supplied to `DatePicker`, expected instance of `Date`.
>       in DatePicker

I searched for an answer to this problem and found a couple of possibilities.

1. The first was to set the default value `defaultValue` to `null` which didn't work.
2. The second answer suggested setting the format to `null` i.e. `format={null}` but that didn't work either.

Here is my code.

**ContactContainer**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { GridColumn, Grid } from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';
import { withState } from './ContactComponent';
import { CommandCell } from './CommandCell';

const ContactsGrid = withState(Grid);

class ContactContainer extends React.Component {    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>                
                <ContactsGrid
                    sortlable
                    pageable
                    pageSize={10}
                    editField="inEdit">
                    <GridColumn field="Id" title="Id" editable={false} width={100} />
                    <GridColumn field="FirstName" title="First Name" />
                    <GridColumn field="LastName" title="Last Name" />
                    <GridColumn field="Email" title="Email" />
                    <GridColumn field="CreatedUser" title="Created By" />
                    <GridColumn field="CreatedDate" title="Created Date" editor="date" format="{0:d}" defaultValue={null} />
                    <GridColumn
                        groupable={false}
                        sortable={false}
                        filterable={false}
                        resizable={false}
                        field="_command"
                        title=" "
                        width="180px"
                        cell={CommandCell}
                    />
                </ContactsGrid>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default ContactContainer;
```

**ContactComponent**

```
import React from 'react';
import { toDataSourceRequestString, translateDataSourceResultGroups } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { Grid, GridToolbar } from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';

export function withState() {
    return class StatefullGrid extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            if (props.pageable === false) {
                this.state = {};
            } else {
                this.state = {
                    dataState: {
                        skip: 0,
                        take: 20
                    }
                };
            }            
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <Grid
                    editField="_command"
                    {...this.props}
                    {...this.state.dataState}
                    total={this.state.total}
                    data={this.state.result}
                    onItemChange={this.itemChange}
                    onDataStateChange={this.onDataStateChange}>
                    <GridToolbar>
                        <Fab size="small" color="secondary" aria-label="Add" onClick={this.addContact}>
                            <AddIcon />
                        </Fab>
                    </GridToolbar>                    
                    {this.props.children}
                </Grid>
            );
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.fetchData(this.state.dataState);
        }       

        addContact = () => {
            const data = this.state.result;            
            data.unshift({ "_command": true, inEdit: true });
            this.setState({
                result: data
            })
        };
        enterEdit = (item) => {
            this.itemInEdit = Object.assign(item, {});
            item.inEdit = true;
            this.forceUpdate();
        };
        cancelEdit = (item) => {
            let data = this.state.result
            let mappedData = data.map(record => {
                if (record.Id === this.itemInEdit.Id) {
                    record = this.itemInEdit;
                    record.inEdit = false
                }
                return record
            })
            this.setState({
                result: mappedData
            })
        };

        handleDataStateChange = (changeEvent) => {
            this.setState({ dataState: changeEvent.Data });
            this.fetchData(changeEvent.data);
        };
        onDataStateChange = (changeEvent) => {
            this.setState({ dataState: changeEvent.Data });
            this.fetchData(changeEvent.Data);
        };
        serialize = (obj) => {
            var str = [];
            for (var p in obj)
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                }
            return str.join("&");
        };
        itemChange = (event) => {
            switch (event.value) {
                case "edit":
                    this.enterEdit(event.dataItem)
                    break;
                case "delete":
                    this.deleteItem(event.dataItem)
                    break;
                case "update":
                    if (event.dataItem.Id) {
                        this.updateItem(event.dataItem)
                    } else {
                        this.addContact(event.dataItem)
                    }
                    break;
                case "cancel":
                    this.cancelEdit(event.dataItem)
                    break;
                default:
                    const data = this.state.result.slice();
                    const index = data.findIndex(d => d.id === event.dataItem.id);
                    data[index] = { ...data[index], [event.field]: event.value };
                    this.setState({
                        result: data
                    });
            }

        };
        fetchData(dataState) {
            const queryStr = `${toDataSourceRequestString(dataState)}`;
            const hasGroups = dataState.group && dataState.group.length;
            const base_url = 'api/Contact/GetContacts';
            const init = { method: 'GET', accept: 'application/json', headers: {} };

            fetch(`${base_url}?${queryStr}`, init)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(({ Data, total }) => {
                    this.setState({
                        result: hasGroups ? translateDataSourceResultGroups(Data) : Data,
                        total,
                        dataState
                    });
                });
        };
    }
}
```

**CommandCell**

```
import React from 'react';
import { GridCell } from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import DoneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Done';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';

export class CommandCell extends GridCell {
    buttonClick = (e, command) => {
        this.props.onChange({ dataItem: this.props.dataItem, e, field: this.props.field, value: command });

    }
    render() {
        if (this.props.rowType !== "data") {
            return null;
        }

        if (this.props.dataItem.inEdit) {
            return (
                <td>
                    <IconButton color="secondary" className="k-grid-save-command"
                        onClick={(e) => this.buttonClick(e, "update")}>
                        <DoneIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <IconButton color="inherit" className="k-grid-cancel-command"
                        onClick={(e) => this.buttonClick(e, "cancel")}>
                        <CloseIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </td>
            );
        }

        return (
            <td>
                <Fab color="secondary" aria-label="Edit" className="k-grid-edit-command" onClick={(e) => this.buttonClick(e, "edit")}>
                    <EditIcon />
                </Fab>
                <Fab color="secondary" aria-label="Delete" className="k-grid-remove-command" onClick={(e) => window.confirm('Confirm deleting: ' + this.props.dataItem.Name) && this.buttonClick(e, "delete")}>
                    <DeleteIcon />
                </Fab>
            </td>
        );
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with a solution to this problem or a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

i think problem is here you have assigned `defaultValue={null}` which throw warning. try passing date in `defaultValue`

`<GridColumn field="CreatedDate" title="Created Date" editor="date" format="{0:d}" defaultValue={new Date()} />`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this hasn't changed anything, the error persists.

Comment: maybe you need to use `moment` library and pass moment method in default value `defaultValue={moment()}`